# Input parameter for perl CGI script

Tags: perl, cgi

I need some insight on my Perl CGI script.

First of all all this is running under webmin so i'm doing a custom module.

I'm calling a CGI Perl script passing 2 parameter from another Perl CGI. The link I'm calling is in the following format:

```
http://IP:8080/foobar/alat.cgi?sysinfo=xxxxxxx&SR=yyyyyyyy
```

### The alat.cgi script look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard); 
ReadParse();
$q = new CGI;
my $dir = $in->param('SR');
my $s = $in->param('sysinfo');
ui_print_header(undef, $text{'edit_title'}.$dir, "");
print $dir."<br>";
print $s"<br>";
```

---

The only output I get printed is the value of `$dir` and `$s` seems to be empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `use strict; use diagnostics;` might be helpful.

Comment: That last line is missing an operator between $s and "<br>" ... is that a typos?

Comment: `$q` is not the same as `$in`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had a number of silly syntax error which finally i was able to detect using the diagnostics. for the same of discussion adding here the corrected script:                                                     #!/usr/bin/perl
# Run alat on selected sysinfo and allow display of output
#use strict; 
use diagnostics;
require 'recoverpoint-lib.pl';
use CGI qw(:standard); 
ReadParse();
my $q = new CGI;
my $dir = $q->param('SR');
my $s = $q->param('sysinfo');

ui_print_header(undef, $text{'edit_title'}.$dir, "");
print  $dir."<br>";
print  $s."<br>";

Comment: Don't keep `use diagnostics` in your code. Only put it in for very specific analysis. It is **very slow** and adds a load of execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Сухой27 said, add `use strict;`, but also `use warnings;` to the top of your script, right below the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/perl`) line. Those will tell you about syntax errors and other stuff where Perl is doing something other than you might intend.

With CGI (which is btw not part of the Perl core in the latest 5.22 release any more) and the object oriented approach you are tyring to take, you don't need to use `ReadParse()`. That is an abomination left in from Perl 4's `cgilib.pl` times.

I don't know what your `ui_print_header` function does. I'm guessing it outputs a bunch of HTML. Are you sure you defined it?

With fixing all your syntax errors and using modern syntax, your program would look like this. I'll break down what is happening for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $dir = $q->param('SR');
my $s = $q->param('sysinfo');

# you need to declare this to use it below
my %text = ( edit_title => 'foo' );

# we declare this sub further down
ui_print_header(undef, $text{'edit_title'} . $dir, q{});

print $dir . '<br />';
print $s . '<br  />';

sub ui_print_header {
  my ( $foo, $title, $dir, $bar ) = @_;

  # do stuff here...
}
```

Let's look at some of the things I did here.

- Saying `new CGI` as the CGI docs suggest is fine, but since we are using the OOP way you can use the more common `CGI->new`. It's the same thing really, but it's consistent with the rest of the OOP Perl world and it's more clear that you are calling the `new` method on the `CGI` package.
- If you have `$q`, keep using it. There is no `$in`.
- Declare all your variables with `my`.
- Declare `%text` so you can use `$text{'edit_title'}` later. Probably you imported that, or ommitted it from the code you showed us.
- Declare `ui_print_header()`. See above.
- `q{}` is the same as `''`, but it's clearer that it's an empty string.

Comment: Check out SawyerX's talk *CGI.pm must die!*, which is extremely entertaining and shows why CGI is outdated: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s - of course you can still use it, but take into account that there are way easier things around today. :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone for the very quick answer, and as I was suspecting I just had some silly mistake.
Adding here the corrected code that now works

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Run alat on selected sysinfo and allow display of output
#use strict; 
use diagnostics;
require 'recoverpoint-lib.pl';
use CGI qw(:standard); 
ReadParse();
my $q = new CGI;
my $dir = $q->param('SR');
my $s = $q->param('sysinfo');

ui_print_header(undef, $text{'edit_title'}.$dir, "");
print  $dir."<br>";
print  $s."<br>";
```

Just to clarify for some of previous answer, this is a custom module of webmin so variable $text is imported and function ui_print_header is a webmin defined one, it basically print the page header in HTML

Comment: `use strict;` should be uncommented.

Answer (score -1):

As you enable **strict** and **warnings** you can easily know the errors.Also you should check Apache error logs, I think the script should be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard); 
use strict;
use warnings;
ReadParse();
my $q = new CGI;
my $dir = $q->param('SR');
my $s = $q->param('sysinfo');
ui_print_header(undef, $text{'edit_title'}.$dir, "");
print $dir."<br>";
print $s."<br>";
```